# Problem with using if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ with php post form submittal

Tags: php, html

I have read several of the posts here however I still do not know what went wrong using  `if(isset($_POST["submit"])` for form submission. I made use of  in htm file. Any ideas? I made use of a form submition button in html and tried to use the press of the submit button to send data from the form to the php page but I keep getting errors.

```css
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){

    $product = $_POST['Product'];
    $description = $_POST['Description'];
    $price = $_POST['Price'];
    $paypal = $_POST['paypal'];
    $shipping = $_POST['shiprice'];
    $photoss = $_POST['image_uploads'];
}
if(empty($product)) {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a product</li>";
}
if(empty($description)) {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a description!</li>";
}
if(empty($price)) {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a price!</li>";
}
if(empty($paypal)) {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your paypal!</li>";
}
if(empty($shipping)) {
    $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a shipping price</li>";
}

echo 'Buy a '.$product.'!';
echo "<br>";
echo 'Description: '.$description.'!';
echo "<br>";
echo 'Price '.$price.'!';
echo "<br>";
echo 'Cost of shipping'.$shipping.'!';
echo "<br>";
echo 'pay to'.$paypal.'!';
?>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="syling.css"/>

<div id = "uploadpage">

<h3>
Please Upload your item that you want to sell here 
</h3>

<div id="navigate">
<h2> Navigation </h2>
<ul>

<li> <a class = "selected" href = "website.htm" >Home </a> </li>
<li>  <a href = "aboutpage.htm" >about </a>  </li>
<li> <a href = "accountpage.htm" >account </a>  </li>
</ul>
</div>

<form action = "formhandling.php" method = "post"  autocomplete = "off" >

<h2>
Item: <input type = "text" name = "Product" value = "" size = "45" maxlength = "70"
</h2>


<h2>
Description: <input type = "text" name = "Description" value = "" size = "45" maxlength = "700"
</h2>

<h2>
Price: <input type = "text" name = "Price" value = "" size = "25" maxlength = "70"
</h2>

<h2>
Paypal Email to get paid: <input type = "text" name = "paypal" value = "" size = "25" maxlength = "200"
</h2>

<h2>
Price to ship: <input type = "text" name = "shiprice" value = "" size = "25" maxlength = "70"
</h2>

<h2>
 <div>
    <label for="image_uploads">Choose images to upload (PNG, JPG)</label>
    <input type="file" id="image_uploads" name="image_uploads" accept=".jpg, .jpeg, .png" multiple>
  </div>
  <div class="preview">
    <p>No files currently selected for upload</p>
  </div>
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" >
</form>
</h2>
```

Comment: All the `if (empty(....))` statements should also be inside `if(isset($_POST['submit']))`

Comment: When I delete the ["submit"] at the top the code in if(isset($_POST["submit"])){ , the code runs fine. I don't know why this is because I used <input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit" > at the bottom.

Comment: What error are you getting?

Comment: what errors you getting?

Comment: `<input type="file" name="image_uploads">` should be get by `$var = $_FILES['image_uploads']['name'];` in php.

Comment: Ok everything works fine when I delete ["submit" ] at the top. Anyone know why this is?

Answer (score 0):

All the code that uses the form submission parameters needs to be inside that `if` statement.

And if any of the inputs are invalid, you should display `$errorMessage` instead of the normal output.

```
<?php
if(isset($_POST["submit"])){
    $product = $_POST['Product'];
    $description = $_POST['Description'];
    $price = $_POST['Price'];
    $paypal = $_POST['paypal'];
    $shipping = $_POST['shiprice'];
    $photoss = $_POST['image_uploads'];
    if(empty($product)) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a product</li>";
    }
    if(empty($description)) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a description!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($price)) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a price!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($paypal)) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter your paypal!</li>";
    }
    if(empty($shipping)) {
        $errorMessage .= "<li>You forgot to enter a shipping price</li>";
    }

    if (empty($errorMessage)) {
        echo 'Buy a '.$product.'!';
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'Description: '.$description.'!';
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'Price '.$price.'!';
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'Cost of shipping'.$shipping.'!';
        echo "<br>";
        echo 'pay to'.$paypal.'!';
    } else {
        echo "<ul>$errorMessage</ul>";
    }
}
?>
```

Comment: I tried running this code with sample form info and nothing Is being printed. You seem to have the right idea. I wonder what is could be.

Comment: Use `var_dump($_POST)` to see what's submitted.

Comment: I found out  that my comment above still seems to be the issue however this made my error messages if the user doenst enter the form work so thank you!

Answer (score -1):

I found out that since wamp was running in internet explore that the code was not running properly. Hmmmmmmm